# How to add a random number to a specific column in matlab function block?

Tags: arrays, matlab, arraylist, random, simulink

I want to create a array 3X2 in Matlab function block that will contains static numbers. As an input on this block i will connect a random number generator and this values i would like to add only in the second column. Please tell my someone how I can do this.

With best regards!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @JBDouble05 This question has nothing to do with Code Review whatsoever. Please take a look at [their help center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) before making any further recommendations.

Answer (score 1):

Input the random number(s) into the MATLAB Function block and add them to the appropriate elements using standard MATLAB notation:

[image]

**NOTE:** The last line of the above code should be `y(:,2) = y(:,2) + u;`